# Deleting x rows every y rows in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

How can I remove (for example) 3 rows every 10 rows?
For example if I have a dataframe with 100 rows at the end I need I dataframe with 70 rows (with missing the first,the second,the third,the eleventh,the twelfth,the thirteenth and so on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a toy dataframe with 100 lines, try this:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = 1:100)
rem <- as.vector(sapply(1:3, function(i) seq(i, nrow(df), 10)))
df[-rem, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `outer` to create a sequence of the rows to remove.

```
result <- df[-c(outer(seq(1, nrow(df), 10), 0:2, `+`)), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do this with `rep` in a vectorized way

```
i1 <- seq(1, nrow(df), 10)
out <- df[-(rep(0:2, each = length(i1)) + i1),]
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = 1:100)
```